# Nested each loop not working

Tags: ruby

I'm going through problems at [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) to gain some experience with Ruby. The problem I'm working on now has me looking at a 1000-digit number and finding the sequence of five consecutive digits with the greatest product.

```
big_num = //1000-digit number
num_array = big_num.split('').map(&:to_i)
biggest = 0
prod = 1

(0..995).each do |x|
 (0..4).each do |y|
   prod *= num_array[x+y]
 end
 biggest = prod if prod > biggest
 prod = 0
end

puts biggest
```

This gives me 882, which is incorrect. To look for the problem, I had it print the values of x and y for each iteration. After the first iteration, it always prints out the five values of y as `7,3,1,6,7`, which, when all multiplied together, equal 882. So, after the first iteration of the outer loop, it's not looking past the first five values of `num_array`, even though x seems to be incrementing properly. For the life of me, I can't figure out why it's behaving this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the nice Enumerable method `each_cons()` to get all sequences of consecutive numbers, eliminating your outer loop. Secondly, I would use `reduce(:*)` to get each product, eliminating your inner loop. Finally I would call `.max` to get your answer.

```
num_array.each_cons(5).map{|seq| seq.reduce(:*)}.max
```

Voilà, one-liner.

Comment: OP, accept this answer. This is the ruby way, this is the FP way, this is the nicely readable way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinitialize `prod` with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you! I originally misread the problem as looking for sum, rather than product, so I just forgot to change that line to 1 instead of 0.